# How to make PUT request in jquery (make file on server)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am tring to use PUT request.I never used before .I used only get and POST request.Now I want to save file on server .In other word I have data and I have location where I want to save/create file with data.can we do using Ajax..can we create file on server ..
I am getting success ,but I don't know file will create or not.?
If I have **json data {data:"test"}**
**saveFilePath:"d:/download/c.text"**

```
function postloadScript(json,saveFilePath){
  var data={path:saveFilePath,jsonData:JSON.parse(json)};
    $.ajax({
        type:"PUT",
        url: 'http://192.167.1.92:8080/aa/authenticate/putrequest?savepar='+saveFilePath,
        contentType: 'application/json',
   //     headers: { path: saveFilePath },
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
       // data: JSON.stringify(data),
        data: json,

        success:function(data){

        console.log(data);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

        },
        error:function(err){
            console.log(err)
            console.log(err.error())
            alert('error'+err);
        }
    });
}
```

MY request is this 
I send save file path with `? savepar='+saveFilePath,`..
But why file is not created on server ?

Comment: We can't tell why your server side code to process the PUT request isn't working because you haven't shown it to us.

Comment: I need to do some coding to server side..Actually server is giving only success or error

Comment: your mean I give only server path .server developer create text file..mean using javascript we can't create text file

Comment: Correct. You can't make an HTTP request to an arbitrary server and create a file on it. That would be a massive security problem.

Comment: ok ..last mean I will give path to server and data ..sever developer will do the rest work ?

Comment: please explain once again..please

Comment: You would need to talk to the server side programmer to find out exactly what format they want the request in.

Comment: ok...I will tell to server developer that we are using client side language we can't create file on server .you have to create that without your code we can't create that.may I right ?